# Time intervals in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, time

I am asking for your help in getting "quarter" of year in my small project.

My VB.NET project is "the daily work done" in a company. I am using Visual Studio 2010 - windows application - SQL Server 2012 and I want to view the "work" happened in quarter of the year 'first quarter, second quarter, ... etc.' that is selected from a combo box in a gridview.

Please help

====the code below is the function that am trying to execute====

```
Public Sub Load_WorkDayTable_By_period(ByVal DateWork As Date)
    WorkDayTable.Clear()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(" select (@DateWork % 100 - 1) / 3 + 1 as [Quarter] From WorkDayTable ", connSQLServer) 
   
    cmd.Parameters.Add("DateWork", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateWork
   
    connSQLServer.Open()
    WorkDayTable.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    connSQLServer.Close()
    cmd = Nothing
End Sub
```

==========and this is the sub that is calling the function

```
Private Sub Com_viewper_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Com_viewper.SelectedIndexChanged
    If Com_viewper.SelectedItem = "الربع الأول" Then

        load_WorkDayTable()
        Load_WorkDayTable_By_period(Com_viewper.SelectedValue)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = WorkDayTable
        With DataGridView1
            .DataSource = WorkDayTable
            .Columns("EmpName").HeaderText = "اسم الشركة"
            .Columns("EmpName").Width = 150
            .Columns("Workk").HeaderText = "الموظف"
            .Columns("Workk").Width = 100
            .Columns("DateWork").HeaderText = "رقم الهاتف"
            .Columns("DateWork").Width = 100
            .Columns("NoteWork").HeaderText = "البريد الالكتروني"
            .Columns("NoteWork").Width = 100
            .Columns("WorkNum").HeaderText = "رقم العمل"
            .Columns("WorkNum").Width = 100
            .Columns("flagg").HeaderText = "مؤشر"
            .Columns("flagg").Width = 120
            .Columns("EmpNum").HeaderText = "رقم الموظف"
            .Columns("EmpNum").Width = 120
            .Columns("Worki").HeaderText = "عمل"
            .Columns("Worki").Width = 100
            .Columns("Workii").HeaderText = "عمل"
            .Columns("Workii").Width = 100
            .Columns("Workc").HeaderText = "عمل"
            .Columns("Workc").Width = 100
            .Columns("Workcc").HeaderText = "عمل"
            .Columns("Workcc").Width = 100
            .Columns("WorkD").HeaderText = "عمل"
            .Columns("WorkD").Width = 100
        End With

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Kinda weird this. You are not actually selecting anything from the table other than the existence of rows. The result is going to be the same for every row. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: am sorry i just forget to add the sub thats calling the function

Comment: use `DATEPART(quarter, date_column)` refer to documentation for more details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: and am trying to retrieve data in specefic time interval <<first quarter , second quarter,...>>

Comment: @DaleK thanks anyway for editing my question

Comment: @AnsamY.B. if you add sample data and expected results someone will most likely answer.

Answer (score 0):

The EndDate is incremented by one because the Dates are 12 AM. You may have to play with that a bit. I had to guess at the name of the date field in you WorkDayTable.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ComboBox1.Items.AddRange({"First Quarter", "Second Quarter", "Third Quarter", "Fourth Quarter"})
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted
    Dim StartDate As Date
    Dim EndDate As Date
    Dim CurrentYear As Integer = Now.Year
    Select Case ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
        Case "First Quarter"
            StartDate = New Date(CurrentYear, 1, 1)
            EndDate = New Date(CurrentYear, 4, 1)
        Case "Second Quarter"
            StartDate = New Date(CurrentYear, 4, 1)
            EndDate = New Date(CurrentYear, 5, 1)
        Case "Third Quarter"
            StartDate = New Date(CurrentYear, 7, 1)
            EndDate = New Date(CurrentYear, 10, 1)
        Case "Fourth Quarter"
            StartDate = New Date(CurrentYear, 10, 1)
            EndDate = New Date(CurrentYear + 1, 1, 1)
        Case Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a quarter")
            Exit Sub
    End Select
    Debug.Print($"{StartDate}, {EndDate}")
    Load_WorkDayTable_By_period(StartDate, EndDate)
End Sub

Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"
Private WorkDayTable As New DataTable

Public Sub Load_WorkDayTable_By_period(StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date)
    WorkDayTable.Clear()
    Using connSQLServer As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New SqlCommand(" select * From WorkDayTable Where WorkDate Between @StartDate And @EndDate;", connSQLServer)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = StartDate
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = EndDate
        connSQLServer.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            WorkDayTable.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to specify a quarter by getting the first day of the desired year and then just adding the appropriate number of months, e.g.

```vb
Private Function GetRecordsByQuarter(year As Integer, quarter as Integer) As DataTable
    Dim firstDayOfYear As New Date(year, 1, 1)
    Dim inclusiveStartDate = firstDayOfYear.AddMonths(3 * (quarter - 1))
    Dim exclusiveEndDate = inclusiveStartDate.AddMonths(3)

    Using adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE CreatedDate >= @StartDate AND CreatedDate < @EndDate",
                                        connectionString)
        With adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters
            .Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = inclusiveStartDate
            .Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = exclusiveEndDate
        End With

        Dim table As New DataTable

        adapter.Fill(table)

        Return table
    End Using
End Function
```